# Посылка данных Modbus RTU

Tags: c#, modbus

Что именно слать этому прибору?

Возможности расходомера «ЭХО-Р»
для работы по протоколу MODBUS

1. Адрес:
   от 1 до 247.
2. Режим:
   RTU или ASCII.
   Примечание. В режиме ASCII в адресованном «Акрону» сообщении интервал между соседними символами должен быть не менее 0,02 с.
3. Скорость, бит/с:
   1200, 2400, 4800, 9600, 19200.
4. Формат.

4.1. Контрольный бит:
а) четность;
б) нечетность;
в) не используется.

4.2. Число стоп-битов:
1 или 2 (без использования контрольного бита – только 2).

5. Воспринимаемые команды:

03 – запрос на передачу архивных данных, или текущих значений скорости или
расхода, или параметров настройки прибора (в соответствии с указанными адресами – см п.6);

08 00 – запрос выполнения диагностической функции Return Query Data.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

впервые сталкиваюсь. вполне хватит примера. вот другим приборам шлю что-то вроде #232 или `write(new byte[1]{0x1f},0,1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Выставляете в приборе настройки и соответственно такие же в своей программе для соединения (Например, режим: Modbus RTU,Скорость 9600, Контрольный бит - не используется, 1 стоп бит). Далее советую использовать функцию формирования посылки, как-то так:

```
public static byte[] ReadHoldingRegister(int id, int startAddress, int length)
{
    byte[] data = new byte[8];

    byte High, Low;
    data[0] = Convert.ToByte(id);                                       
    data[1] = Convert.ToByte(3);                                         
    byte[] _adr = BitConverter.GetBytes(startAddress-1);
    data[2] = _adr[1];                                  
    data[3] = _adr[0];                                  
    byte[] _length = BitConverter.GetBytes(length);
    data[4] = _length[1];
    data[5] = _length[0];
    myCRC(data, 6, out High, out Low);
    data[6] = Low;
    data[7] = High;
    return data;
}
```

Для расчета контрольной суммы можно использовать например такую функцию:

```
public static void myCRC(byte[] message, int length, out byte CRCHigh, out byte CRCLow)
{
    ushort CRCFull = 0xFFFF;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        CRCFull = (ushort)(CRCFull ^ message[i]);
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            if ((CRCFull & 0x0001) == 0)
                CRCFull = (ushort)(CRCFull >> 1);
            else
            {
                CRCFull = (ushort)((CRCFull >> 1) ^ 0xA001);
            }
        }
    }
    CRCHigh = (byte)((CRCFull >> 8) & 0xFF);
    CRCLow = (byte)(CRCFull & 0xFF);
}
```

И далее в коде программы вычисляете посылку и отправляете ее по СОМ-порту:

```
_serialPort.Write(ReadHoldingRegister(123,21,1),0,8);
```

где:
 123 - номер устройства;
 21  - первый регистр (выделеный на картинке);
 1   - длина, которую необходимо считать. Тоесть если вы напишете 2, то в ответной посылке вам также прийдет и 22 регстр (Если верить скриншоту это коды указателей архивов часовых и суточных значений).